# MikTeX cannot find the file

Tags: xetex, miktex

Why is it that MikTeX's XeTeX cannot find my file?

[image]

Dude, you're right there in the same directory as the file, why can't you see it?!

Comment: Just for the fun of it, what does `kpsewhich pikakoe.tex` say?

Comment: Your document is inside the miktex tree. miktex will not search it there. Documents don't belong in application folders (and the miktex tree is an application folder). Put it in a documentation folder. (Addition: miktex will perhaps find the document if you update the FNDB, but then the next problem will be that it doesn't find the aux or the toc).

Comment: @Ulrike: A-ha, thanks! Although I'd appreciate if I could be in charge where my documents can and cannot be. `;-)` I mean, why does it need to "search" it anywhere? I am in the directory where it is; it is of no MiKTeX's concern to search my documents from anywhere. Does not compute.

Comment: See it as a security feature: Imagine that you try to compile inside the bin-folder a document which generates a file called `MiKTeX209-xetex.dll`. You can easily do a lot damage with a compilation inside a texmf tree as a compilation has to be able to overwrite files like e.g. toc or pdf. Beside this: even if the document is nearby it must be found, if the current directory is not in the search path then files there are not found.

Comment: @Ulrike: Well, I can think of a gazillion *other* ways to do damage , none of which MiKTeX is protecting against (say, pressing delete on the whole folder structure). But anyway, I digress, your comment answered my question, mind converting that to an answer so I could accept it? `:-)`

Comment: @Ulrike: "if the current directory is not in the search path then files there are not found.". Eh? I'm assuming you meant the binaries, not the documents need to be in the SEARCH PATH (PATH env var). Because that would make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I meant documents. And I didn't meant the PATH-variable but the (in texlive speak) kpse search path. xetex searches for files along the pathes set up in `miktex\config\xetex.ini`. This `ini` contains beside others the declaration `path=.`. That's why xetex searches also the current directory. If you would remove this line it would no longer work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your document is inside the miktex tree. miktex will not search it there. Documents don't belong in application folders (and the miktex tree is an application folder). Put it in a documentation folder. (Addition: Depending on the concrete location of the document in the texmf tree miktex will perhaps find it if you update the FNDB, but then the next problem will be that it doesn't find the `aux` or the `toc`). –

See it as a security feature: Imagine that you try to compile inside the `bin`-folder a document which generates a file called `MiKTeX209-xetex.dll`. You can easily do a lot damage with a compilation inside a texmf tree as a compilation has to be able to overwrite files like e.g. `toc` or `pdf`.