# Running .ins file with terminal and user command

Tags: packages, installing, terminal-output

I'm using a portable version of MiKTeX 2.9 on an external hard drive on a pc without admin rights.

I try running an .ins file with TeXmaker terminal using 'latex NameOfPackage.ins', but it says can't find file NameOfPackage.ins.
I first placed the file inside the MiKTeX tree and updated the FNDB, which didn't work.
I then tried placing it ouside the tree, with which it still couldn't find the file

I used a user command in texmaker to compile the .ins file, which gave the error:
    no log file found

```sh
"E:/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/latex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.ins
```

I used a user command before, with success, but after settings reset I don't know exactly what the command was, so I might have done this wrong

Edit:
While i tried running the same command again it gave an emergency stop for the line

```
\generate{\file{dutch.ldf}{\from{dutch.dtx}{code}}}
```

dutch.ldf was already in the folder, so I deleted the file and tried again.
It worked this time, so the problem seem to be solved.
I would guess it is best to delete the files that where generated when the problem occured, to avoid problems like this

The place where I found the command for .ins:
[tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123129](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123129/error-when-compiling-xcolor-ins-in-texmaker-to-generate-xcolor-sty-file)

I would still like to know why using the terminal doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do any of the suggestions under http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113433/15925 help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.ins` and `.dtx` are source files, they are usually sorted into the `source` subtree of a TDS tree (`texmf/source/latex/babel/babel.ins`).

The files in a TDS tree are organized in such a way, that source, documentation files are *not* searched, when TeX looks for its input/package/class files. This reduces the search space and makes file look-up faster.

But on the other side, it is not possible to call generate source files from somewhere else, because `.ins` or `.dtx` files are not found outside of the sub tree `TDS:tex/`. Either

- these files can be compiled in the directory, where they are:

  ```
  cd source\latex\babel
  tex babel.ins
  ```

  However, this will not work in MiKTeX because of a security feature.
  See [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68174/16967) (MiKTeX does not find files in application directories).
- Copy the files to a fresh scratch directory and compile there:

  ```
  md scratch
  copy source\latex\babel/* scratch
  cd scratch
  tex babel.ins
  ```

  (The path before `source\...` is omitted in both examples and needs to be added.)

Usually LaTeX installation files `.ins` can be run by plain TeX (`tex`), because the `.ins` files are based on `docstrip`, which does not need the LaTeX format. In some cases, LaTeX is needed nevertheless, sometimes only because of some silly `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}`.

Typically a LaTeX user do not need to run `.ins` files, because the TeX distribution provides the packages unpacked already. If the TeX distribution does not contains the package, then CTAN might have `package.tds.zip` files below `CTAN:install/`. They only need to be unpacked at the root of the TDS tree (plus refreshing the file name database).

### Problem (c) "Command not found", discussed in the comment section

MiKTeX portable does not add its directory `bin` to the environment variable `PATH`. Therefore Windows is not able to find the binaries, if they are not qualified with a sufficient path component. This is the price of being portable. The host system remains untouched and the path of the `bin` folder can change (different USB drive letters, ...).

In order to  use MiKTeX portable with a command window, `miktex-portable` in the installation directory of MiKTeX portable should be called first. It adds an icon to the task bar. A right click offers the option "Command Prompt", which opens a command window, where the environment variables for MiKTeX are set. See ["How to use MiKTeX portable"](http://miktex.org/portable).

If you want to use MiKTeX on your system permanently, then the normal MiKTeX version is preferable. Otherwise, the environment variables can be configures manually in the Windows system, if the `bin` folder has a permanent location or the previously described way can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When trying to run latex babel.ins in the directory where babel is: "E:\MiKTeX 2.9\source\latex\babel", I get an error saying: 'latex is not recognized as een internal or external command'. My path in texmaker is set to: "E:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin" which should be correct

Comment: @Tom If `latex` should be executed without specifying the full path, the directory `E:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` should be added to the environment variable `PATH`. The portable version of MiKTeX does this not automatically, but AFAIK it provides a command window, where the variable is set.

Comment: The PATH is already set to E:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin as mentioned in my earlier comment via the texmaker configuration

Comment: @Tom `echo %PATH%` shows the setting in a command window.

Comment: echo %PATH% gives a couple windows path's and path's from other programs and also E:\MiKTeX 2.9\aMiKTeX\miktex\bin\. So I don't see why it shouldn't work

Comment: @Tom Perhaps you are using different command windows with different settings. Also there is a wild intermix of problems, (a) LaTeX, the command is not found, (b) LaTeX is run, but no `.log` file, (c) LaTeX is run, but with an error message, ...

Comment: (a) The problem of 'command not found' is solved. I am using the correct command to compile the .ini
(b) The problems of no log file is still the same. When I use a log file from an older version of babel, it just says 'no errors', but doesn't compile.
(c) compiling via command window gives error 'latex not recognized when ran in "texmf/source/latex/babel/babel.ins" and '.ins not found' in E:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\.
Should I open different questions for the problems a, b and c

Comment: Thanks for the further answer. When posting this question I used the command prompt via the editor, TeXmaker. Now I used the command prompt via the option 'command prompt' in MiKTeX. Now it can find latex.exe, but when trying to use the command in 'E:\MiKTeX 2.9\source\latex\babel', where I placed the babel.ins file, it still says that it can't find the file.

So the command 'latex' is working, but can't find .ins file

Comment: @Tom You have to go into the directory with the `.ins` file. See the first part of my answer for more details.

Comment: babel.ins is in E:\MiKTeX2.9\source\latex\babel\; so I use cd E:\MiKTeX 2.9\source\latex\babel\. Then I use command 'latex babel.ins'; then I get the error: This is pdfTeX, version (the version name)  entering extended mode ! I can't find file 'babel.ins'. <*> babel.ins. BTW how do I get that grey background behind .ins?

Comment: @Tom AFAIK a security feature of MiKTeX, see [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68174/16967). The code markup with back ticks also works in comments.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I will mark this answer as accepted.
I know placed the babel map outside the MiKTeX tree and now it also works via the command prompt. Maybe you can also revert to ulrike's answer in yours

Comment: @Tom I have already added a link to Ulrike's answer. Since the method would work with other TeX distributions (TeX Live), I keep it in the answer.