# I can't latex the eledmac.ins and eledpar.ins

Tags: installing, eledmac, eledpar

When I try to run latex on eledmac.ins I get an error saying that 'Log File not found', although in the directory a log is created with the name texput.log with the following info:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2013.7.24)  1 APR 2015 05:26
>
> entering extended mode
>
> **eledmac.tex
>
> ! Emergency stop.
>
> <*> eledmac.tex
>
> *** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
>
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>
> 2 strings out of 494046
>
> 17 string characters out of 3148395
>
> 48890 words of memory out of 3000000
>
> 3399 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
>
> 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
>
> 715 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>
> 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
>
> No pages of output.

And the same is happening with eledpar.ins. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are latexing eledmac.tex.
Run `latex eledmac.ins`.

Comment: yes, latex eledmac.ins will be better. But why do want to run it and not use the miktex package manager to update it ?

Comment: I am latexing eledmac.ins. The log just shows eledmac.tex. I don't know why.
The first time I've installed it, I've done it manually. So I was doing it again. 
I've just tried Miktex packager manager and it is not opening wizard. I've just tried to go by miktek settings and I've managed it.

Comment: Well, after the update just get the 'no room for a new write error'. I've reversed it to previous version (from 2013) and the fill compiles again fine. I just can't deal with footnotes spawning to the next page and creating blank pages just for them (which was the reason I wanted to update for).

Comment: in this case, please open an issue on github with you MWE. Your "no room for a new write error" is strange and could be made by loading a lot of package...

Comment: I think your miktex problem with .ins file could be solve reading http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218056/7712

Comment: Can't I just declare the new commands I need? The \footnoteAnomk, the \footnoteAmk, maybe the \onlysideX... It's a 2000+ pages document and I'm not very code-educated to debug all problems. Yes, I do have a lot of packages. (And to adress later, I have a lot of badboxes, but that I'm saving for last.) All I wanted to prevent for now is that notes not to flow to the next page, or to flow into the next page without making a blank page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22487/discussion-between-maieul-and-john).